Inject Illuminate\Http\Request instance in the policy
I want to automatically inject the Request instance in the policy to perform some checks related to the request instance, like it's automatically injected by the service container in the controllers. How is it possible to be done in the policy?
class GroupPolicy extends Policy
{
    public function delete(User $user, Request $request): Response
    {
        $message = 'This is a message';

        if ($message) {
            return Response::deny($message);
        }

        return Response::allow();
    }
}


Unfortunately, Laravel does not automatically inject the Request instance into policies. However, you can retrieve the current Request instance using the request() helper, which accesses the service container to provide the active Request object (https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/helpers#method-request):
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;

class GroupPolicy
{
    public function delete(User $user): Response
    {
        
        $request = request();

        $message = 'This is a message based on request';
        
        if ($message) {
            return Response::deny($message);
        }

        return Response::allow();
    }
}

This allows you to use the Request within your policy methods as needed.

Why will it work?

As rozsazoltan rightfully asks, why will this work? Explaining why it works will help make this answer more future-proof and possibly more helpful to others.

@rozsazoltan - you are correct, my bad -- I have updated my answer

I found also the request() helper: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/helpers#method-request

@csandreas1 good point, I have updated to include that instead -- since it is more straightforward
